# Is it possible to send source file as URL with hylaFax?

Tags: fax

I need to send a fax where the source file is coming from an HTTP URL. I have configured  *hylaFax*. When trying a local file, it works fine. But with a URL it gives an error.

The command I am using is something like this:

```
sendfax -v -h faxhost -f kaur@xyz.com -D -d 1234567890 \
    'http://kaur.dev.xyz.com:7771/app-name/proxy?bName=Test&oName=1.txt'
```

The error:

> Error : 'Can not open file'

The file is downloading when connecting through browser.

Answer (score 0):

sendfax will process stdin so you can pipe documents in:

```
wget -O - 'http://kaur.dev.xyz.com:7771/app-name/proxy?bName=Test&oName=1.txt' | sendfax -v -h faxhost -f kaur@xyz.com -D -d 1234567890
```

or

```
curl 'http://kaur.dev.xyz.com:7771/app-name/proxy?bName=Test&oName=1.txt' | sendfax -v -h faxhost -f kaur@xyz.com -D -d 1234567890
```